# Title от Navigation Controller'a отображается не по центру

Tags: xcode, swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

Проблема такая: тайтл нав бара почему то не отображается по центру на некоторых контроллерах.

[image]

Первая мысль была, что это из-за длинного тайтла. Нет.

Во-первых, на этот контроллер можно попасть двумя путями, и если по второму пути пройти на него, то там тайтл нормально отображается.

Во-вторых, этот скриншот сделан на iphone SE. На iphone 7+, например, этот контроллер выглядит нормально, но вот другой контроллер, который на SE выглядит нормально, на 7+ опять же глючит:

[image]

Как видно, здесь уже короткое название.

Выше говорил про то, что до первого показанного контроллера можно добраться двумя путями. Думал, что и здесь что то может быть, но оба способа абсолютно идентичны, то есть все тот же пуш-переход и там и там.

Пробовал ставить название тайтла как через navigationItem в Storyboard, так и в коде:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    navigationItem.title = "Акции"
}
```

Так же, пробовал создавать в этом месте кастомный тайтл, то есть создавать UIView, на нее пихать текст и присваивать ее navigationBar.titleView. В итоге кастомная вьюха точно так же криво отображается.

На реальных устройствах так же пробовал запускать - тоже самое.

Ума не приложу, в чем может быть дело. Наверняка это какой то эпловский баг, но как мне его обойти?

Comment: Поведение похоже на абсолютное выравнивание по краю.

Comment: Можете приложить пример проекта где воспроизводится эта проблема?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников на втором скрине непонятно тогда, почему край так близко к центру, а не рядом с правой частью экрана, но все равно попробую прописать.

Comment: @VAndrJ, к сожалению, нет. Рабочий проект..

Answer (score 0):

Все, вопрос снят. Чтобы убрать тайтл от backButton, я его просто наверх сдвинул и забыл что он вообще существует. А оказывается вот как это выглядит:

[image]

Ох уж этот путь от новичка до профи...